Godel's incompleteness theorem: Question about effective axiomatization
I am studying Godel incompleteness theorems and I am struggling with the definition of effective axiomatization.
From Wikipedia:

A formal system is said to be effectively axiomatized (also called
effectively generated) if its set of theorems is recursively
enumerable. This means that there is a computer program that, in
principle, could enumerate all the theorems of the system without
listing any statements that are not theorems. Examples of effectively
generated theories include Peano arithmetic and Zermelo–Fraenkel set
theory (ZFC).1
The theory known as true arithmetic consists of all true statements
about the standard integers in the language of Peano arithmetic. This
theory is consistent and complete, and contains a sufficient amount of
arithmetic. However, it does not have a recursively enumerable set of
axioms and thus does not satisfy the hypotheses of the incompleteness
theorems.

I have some intuitive idea of what effective axiomatization means... We need it to be able to recognize valid theorems and proofs, we need to check which axioms are part of that.
But I don't understand the definition of effective axiomatization. Probably because it refers to computer programs. Isn't that weird? How come we can't have a mathematical definition instead?
UPDATE: I realize even if I get the definition, I am lacking some intuition behind it, I would appreciate seeing some example of an algorithm that is axiomatizing a theory. E.g., for Peano arithmetic or ZFC.

Computer programs are perfectly mathematical. If you prefer you can rephrase the definition in terms of Turing machines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine

Or primitive recursive functions.

Ah, I see. Maybe my question could be modified, because I have trouble seeing the intuition behind the axiomatization algorithm, e.g. how it is used on an example such as Peano arithmetic or ZFC.
E.g. what exactly could be happening, how can such algorithm run? It is not that intuitive for me, and given that computers were probably developed later than Godel made this theorem, how did he come with this assumption for the theorem?

Note (re: @NaïmFavier's comment) that the following are equivalent for a theory $T$: $T$ is recursively enumerably axiomatizable; $T$ is recursively axiomatizable; $T$ is primitive recursively axiomatizable. (We can go even lower FWIW.) This is known as Craig's trick and is a consequence of the fact that Kleene's $T$-predicate is itself primitive recursive.

@TerezaTizkova Godel worked at the level of primitive recursive (p.r.) functions, so his version would have been (something like) "If $T$ is a theory whose set of Godel numbers has primitive recursive characteristic function, then [stuff]." To see that (say) ZFC is p.r. in this sense, just think about how difficult it is to tell whether a sentence $\varphi$ is a ZFC axiom (not theorem): we first check finitely many special cases (Powerset/Extensionality/Foundation/Choice/Union/Pairing/Infinity), and then - if $\varphi$ isn't any of those - we check whether $\varphi$ fits the pattern (cont'd)

of Separation or of Replacement. In each case, we don't have to search through arbitrary instances of the relevant scheme, only those generated by a formula of length less than that of $\varphi$, so this is p.r. See also this old answer of mine. (Throughout this and the previous comment, I've conflated the sentence $\varphi$ with its Godel number for convenience. That said, if we set up computability in terms of arbitrary strings or similar, this "translation" isn't needed.)

As @NoahSchweber pointed out, the hypothesis about the set of axioms can be taken to be "primitive recursive" or "recursive" or "recursively enumerable" without making any real difference. But the hypothesis about the set of theorems (as in your quote from Wikipedia) has to be "recursively enumerable". Even if the set of axioms is primitive recursive (as is the case with PA or ZFC), the set  of theorems is only recursively enumerable. (I think the point of the theorem is easier to understand if, like Noah, you express the hypothesis as being about the axioms, not the theorems.)

To close the loop re: @AndreasBlass's comment: if $T$ is r.e. then $T$ is r.e. axiomatizable (take the silly axiomatization consisting of all sentences in $T$), and so by Craig's trick $T$ is p.r. axiomatizable. So Craig's trick is really powerful: it collapses a whole range of prima facie different levels of computational complexity of theories.

See linked post is Noah's comemnt above Why is ZFC recursively axiomatizable

Thank you all! I think it's a lot of new concepts at once for me, so I need to sit with it and play with the different definitions. Craig's trick is great!
